# IIS performance bottlenek

Tags: asp.net, iis

We've got an interesting phenomenon and perhaps some of the IIS experts can give us some hints.

I am running an ASP.NET site in IIS. It is a site where users are playing games, so they are active for a long time and there is some computation on the server side. If the number of parallel users hits a certain level, CPU load goes to 100% and the site becomes unusable. This is not linear: Once a certain level is reached, each new user brings us nearer to doom and fast.

OK, time for more hardware (CPU, memory or whatever) you would think.

Now, the interesting part: We got a second instance of the same site on the same server, using the same files, the same database. Even when the first site is nearly down and the CPU is at 100%, the second site on the same server is still running smoothly. If some users switch from site one to two, everything is fine.

We already found one setting which is helpful: When we increased the standard number of parallel threads for an IIS site from 25 to 100, we could raise the critical number of users by 25%

Are there any other hints what could cause this behaviour? Are there other settings where IIS is throttling?

Comment: Are your users making many HTTP requests or simply holding HTTP requests open for a long time? Have you tried tracing to see what is actually happening on the server when you're problems start?

Comment: Both: We use SignalR where old browsers still use longpolling. But also many requests. Question is which indicators would be best to watch with perfmon.

Comment: Generally speaking there is no shortcut. You should capture hang dumps when CPU usage is high and analyze the cause, or equivalently use a profiler. Tuning threads like https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/821268/contention-poor-performance-and-deadlocks-when-you-make-calls-to-web-s might help, but really you should be caution.